# How to convert MessageHandler in .NetFramework to AspNet.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have below message handler to return some custom messages, and I am registering in WebAPIConfig.Register method in .NetFramework, but I am having troubles with .Net Core as it looks like message handlers are removed in .NET core, I am getting some issues converting it.

```
    public class WebApiCustomMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                request.Properties.Remove(HttpPropertyKeys.NoRouteMatched);
                var errorResponse = request.CreateResponse(response.StatusCode, "resource not found.");
                return errorResponse;
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
```

registering in WebAPIConfig.Register method:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
      config.MessageHandlers.Add(new WebApiCustomMessageHandler());
    }
```

**.NET Core implementation:**

I have below code but it gives errors on creating response and and returning it.

```
        public class WebApiCustomMiddleware
        {
            private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    
            public WebApiCustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
            {
                _next = next;
            }
    
            public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
            {
                //process context.Request
    
                await _next(context);

                //process context.Response
    
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                   context.Request.Properties.Remove(HttpPropertyKeys.NoRouteMatched);
                   var errorResponse = context.Request.CreateResponse(context.Response.StatusCode, "resource not found.");
                   return errorResponse;
                }
                 
               return response;
                  
            }
        }
```

How do I create response and return in .net core middleware it is giving errors as it doesn't have context.Request.Properties, context.Request.CreateResponse, and also what would be the return type ?

```
context.Request.Properties.Remove(HttpPropertyKeys.NoRouteMatched);
var errorResponse = context.Request.CreateResponse(context.Response.StatusCode, "resource not found.");
return errorResponse;
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You've posted code and asked us to port it for you. Please do some research and make and effort on your own. If you get stuck, then ask a question here.

Comment: I did some research Ian Kemp, and that's how I got to know about middleware in .NET Core, I am having trouble in implementing that do you want me to post that code as well. It would be very helpful if we have an answer in .NET core on how to implement this, I did not find it in stackoverflow on how to do it.

Comment: you should read about middleware in `asp.net core` first. That's required and should be done, unless you are not a developer or simply you don't want to be professional in `asp.net core` or at worse you just want to complete the task ***once*** and never want to understand it. That's so bad and even unfair for many other professionals in the same team, who have to assist the others who don't want to follow the latest technologies and just try to complete the tasks on deadline. Such developers work like a robot with no passion. I've personally been affected by those kinds of developer.

Comment: @KingKing did you see what I currently have ? I did read about it, what is wrong if I am facing some issue in figuring out something and wanted help.. I did not just ask on how to do it, I am having errors doing it and looking on how to fix it.. do you have any suggestion to fix it ?

Comment: my comment had been written before your update. Beside understanding about middlewares in `asp.net core`, you need to map the concepts from `HttpRequestMessage` to `HttpContext`, in this case I believe that `HttpRequestMessage.Properties` is mapped to `HttpContext.Items`, to write the response, just use `HttpContext.Response`, it has `StatusCode` property and a `WriteAsync` method to write a string to the response. That's enough for your conversion.

Comment: Thanks @King King do we need context.Items.Remove(HttpPropertyKeys.NoRouteMatched); from microsoft documentation it says "Provides a key that indicates whether the request failed to match a route", but do we need to remove that from context.Items ?

Comment: I'm not so sure about how that property is used in the old message handler, looks like it's for the next message handlers to handle correctly. Read your old message handler  carefully, I think it's a bit strange when you have a `response.StatusCode` of 404 but then you create another `HttpResponseMessage` to return - that sounds strange. Not sure what kind of logic it is, maybe some kind of `response overriding`? In your case, a new response is created to wrap a custom message. I think there is no such thing like `HttpPropertyKeys.NoRouteMatched` so you can remove that.

Comment: @KingKing thank you, yes it's for response override with custom messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the Implementation (thanks to @King King):

```
    public class WebApiCustomMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public WebApiCustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            //process context.Request
            //to do like validating api keys, request headers etc..

            await _next(context);

            //process context.Response
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    statusCode = 404,
                    message = "resource not found"
                }));
            }
            else if(...)
            {}
        }
    }
```

And register in statup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
   app.UseMiddleware<WebApiCustomMiddleware>();
}
```